# Get base type of a methods out/ref parameter

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm digging around in C# reflection but have encountered a problem.

If I reflect over the following method with the intent of retrieving the parameter types, then i'm unable to get the base type when the parameter have either the `out` or `ref`:

```
public void MyMethod(out int first, ref string second) {  }
```

The two parameter types returned are:

```
System.Int32&
System.String&
```

How do i get the base method in code, that is without the Ampersand postfixed?

Here are the boiled down way i retrieve the parameters:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(MyMethod().GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType)
```

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033639/reflection-how-to-get-the-underlying-type-of-a-by-ref-type contains the answer to your question :) Let me know if it does, so that we can close it as a dupe

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: Hot diggity  that was a homerun!! Thanks for the link :-)